# PHP PDO Insert gives Parse Error: expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `'{'' or `'$'', help?

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, insert, pdo

I'm very simply inserting a record into a database using PDO, but I get a parse error

> expecting `T_STRING' or`T_VARIABLE'
>   or `'{'' or`'$''

which I don't understand. Here's my code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "refrigerator";
$pass = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "lifelapse";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

$data = array( 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'email' => $email );

$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) values (:username, :password, :email)");
$STH->execute($data);

header("Location: confirmation.html");    

?>
```

The error is in the line

```
$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) values (:username, :password, :email)");
```

Can anyone shed some light onto this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply a function.

ie:

`$DBH->("INSERT`

To

```
 $DBH->prepare("INSERT
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what should I replace 'methodname' with?

Comment: No, it needs to be `prepare`, not `query`.

Comment: prepare... as suggested by @lonesomeday

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are not calling a method on that line. It should be:

```
 $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) values (:username, :password, :email)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`PDO::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) -- you're not actually calling a function.

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) values (:username, :password, :email)");
```